# Are the Q-values of DQN bounded at a single timestep?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn

Consider that we have an agent that has a set of thousands of different actions at each timestep. The reward function in $R:S \rightarrow\{0,1\}$. Let $Q_{t}^\pi(s,a)$ be the estimate from the neural network in the DQN. At timestep $t \leq T$, where $T$ is the horizon of the RL task, is there any possible way to upper bound

$$ max_a Q_{t}^\pi(s,a) - min_a Q_{t}^\pi(s,a) $$

where $\pi$ is the policy of DQN's Q-network (Neural Net regressor)?

Comment: I deleted my answer. Could you make it clearer that $Q^{\pi}_t(s,a)$ is the estimate from the neural network in the DQN? Just because $\pi$ is from the estimator, it does not mean that $Q^{\pi}$ has to be - you could be asking about bounds from an oracle or assumed well-converged estimator. For the DQN I think there is no theoretical upper bound without stating a lot more conditions.

Comment: Can I clip the output of the NN estimator to be in [0, T] ? Then, the upper bound will be T. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes you can, and that may be a reasonable bound to clip to, because it is theoretical min and max bounds of the system regardless of the policy. I cannot say whether that would be helpful in your project.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: For what reason would you want to clip your q vals? I suggest for training to clip the gradient norm of the network instead of the q values. This will lead to much better results because it preserves the scaling of the gradient while reducing updates that are too big.

Comment: Because I want to create an upper bound of $Q^\pi$ in mathematical analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can. Assume that you want to upper bound your difference to $k$. Use the following function:

$$
y_{t}^{\pi} = \frac{k}{2}*\tanh(Q_{t}^{\pi}(s,a))
$$

Here, $y_{t}^{\pi} \in [-\frac{k}{2}, \frac{k}{2}]$. Hence the upper bound would be $k$.
[Checkout this tanh graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lvefqyb3ap?lang=en).

A practical suggestion - Try to soften out the sharp edjes of tanh by using
$$\frac{k}{2} * \tanh(\frac{2}{k} * Q_{t}^{\pi}(s,a))$$

This is numerically safer. Because the difference between the $\tanh$ outputs reduces drastically when you start going to extreme values in both directions.

Comment: Thanks. Or one can set an output clipping value to [0,T] (regarding binary reward) for horizon T, taking into account that the real Q-values <= T-t at time t.